# Why overloading operator doesn't sets main object to value set

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

On the example below, why `other.age` outputs 88 instead of 0?

```
#include <atlstr.h>//CString for non-MFC
class A
{
public:
    A() : name("Nobody"), age(0) {}
    ~A(){};


    A( CString name, unsigned age ) : name( name ), age( age ) {}
    A& operator=( const A& ref )
    {
        name = ref.name;
        age = 0;
    }

    CString name;
    unsigned int age;
};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{

    A person( CString("Michael"), 88 );
    A other = person;

    std::cout << other.name << std::endl << other.age;
}
```

Comment: Your operator= should return *this;  Are you ignoring a compiler warning/error?

Comment: Yes I've written it, this is pure example only, also VS2003 doesn't displays an error for this example unless the operator is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A other = person;
```

calls `copy c-tor`, that is implicitly defined by compiler, not `operator =`.

12.8/4

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. Thus, for
> the class definition
>
> ```
> struct X {
> X(const X&, int);
> };
> ```
>
> a copy constructor is implicitly-declared.

12.8/8

> The implicitly-defined copy constructor for class X performs a memberwise copy of its subobjects. The
> order of copying is the same as the order of initialization of bases and members in a user-defined construc-
> tor (see 12.6.2). Each subobject is copied in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> — if the subobject is of class type, the copy constructor for the class is used;
>
> — if the subobject is an array, each element is copied, in the manner appropriate to the element type;
>
> — if the subobject is of scalar type, the built-in assignment operator is used.

Quotes are from C++03 standard.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not using the assignment-operator, you're using copy-construction.

```
A other = person;
```

is equivalent to†:

```
A other(A(person));
```

and because you haven't explicitly specified your copy-constructor, the default one is used. This is a member-wise copy, leaving 88 as the value of `age`. This uses your operator:

```
A other;
other = person;
```

---

†Yes, that's a copy of a copy. Note that your compiler will, with optimizations turned on, turns this into:

```
A other(person);
```

through copy-elison. In general, this:

```
T x = y;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
T x(T(y));
```

which will become this (after optimization):

```
T x(y);
```

as long as `T` is copyable or moveable.

Comment: So `A other; other = person;` is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: What would a copy constructor be to set `age` to 0 by directly using `other = person`?

Comment: A( const A& ref) name(ref.name), age(0) {}